# Does a Gemach that lends money need a Prozbul?

Tags: shmita, borrowing, charity, pruzbul

Does a Gemach that lends money need a Prozbul?

Individuals protect their loans from loss in the seventh year through [Prozbul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prozbul). Does a Gemach run by a committee of three need the same protection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [Choshen Mishpat 67:28](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%97%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9F_%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A4%D7%98_%D7%A1%D7%96_%D7%9B%D7%97) it is written that minor orphans do not require *prozbul,* because their guardians are *batei din,* and the source for this ruling is on [Bava Kamma 36b](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Kamma.36b.17)–37a (see also [Gittin 37a](https://www.sefaria.org/Gittin.37a.2)). Here the [Rashba comments](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashba_on_Bava_Kamma.36b.8) that the money owed to a charity fund is not released in the seventh year either, because the guardians of such funds are courts. And [most](http://www.shut-halacha.co.il/q/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%96%D7%91%D7%95%D7%9C-%D7%92%D7%9E%D7%97-4814) articles I've found confirmed this view, but many said that it is still a good idea to be cautious and [write a prozbul](https://www.hidabroot.org/article/78268) in any case. Others raise the concern that these charity funds often give loans both to the poor and the rich, so the managers of the fund [should include](http://nezayon.s163.upress.link/2015/09/07/%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99-%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%98%D7%AA-%D7%9B%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9D/) these loans in their own *prozbul* (see also [Shevut Yitzchak Vol. 15 5:4](https://tablet.otzar.org/pages/?&pagenum=279&book=601572)). [Or LeTzion on Sheviit 7:8](https://tablet.otzar.org/pages/?&pagenum=97&book=11378) discusses a fund belonging to a single person, where he rules that a *prozbul* is required (see also [Vaychal Mosheh 2:52](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=60821&st=&pgnum=344)). Therefore, R' Chayim Kanievsky ruled in [Derekh Emunah Vol. 4 Ch. 9](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=58665&st=&pgnum=348) that due to all these debates the agreements should be written.

See also [this great survey](https://tablet.otzar.org/pages/?&pagenum=38&book=149839) with many sources by the *beit din* [Darkhei Horaah](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%A8_%D7%95%D7%99%D7%99%D7%A1), or this overview in [Otzar Piskei Sheviit](https://tablet.otzar.org/pages/?&pagenum=162&book=85568).